# Does the static keyword give any performance increase?

Tags: c++, performance

I appreciate that this is a micro-optimization, but I am interested in whether declaring either a function or member variable as `static` provides any performance increase compared to a non-`static` implementation?

I remember reading that `const` can be used for compilers to optimize, so it made me wonder whether `static` had any similar advantages.

Comment: There are no `static` classes in C++

Comment: Never realised that! But edited to reflect...

Comment: The real question is: _why do you care_?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference as long as we are not talking about virutal methods here. After all it just affects the scope of the variables

Comment: where is the duplicate??? voting to reopen.

Comment: The usual answer to micro-optimizations is to try it and measure, because it's not easy to predict the outcome. The instructions will be different so the possibility of a speedup does exist.

Comment: How is that a duplicate? That only mentions functions?

Comment: In the cases you're talking about, making something `static` changes its character enough that this is a bit like asking: "which is faster: ice cream or singing?"

Comment: ice cream, of course, is slower.

Comment: This **is not a duplicate of the linked question** - that one is about a static member function vs. a free function, this is about a static vs. non-static member function.

Comment: and this question is also different because it asks about data, which is or may be a member variable.

Comment: While the reason given for closing is wrong, I'm hard put to vote to reopen, because it was still a pretty pointless question and (at least in this case) I don't see much point in reopening just to be able to vote to close for a different reason...

Comment: @JerryCoffin, it's only pointless if you already know the answer.

Comment: @Jerry- I could find a lot of your questions pointless- but I wouldnt close them if they followed the guidelines. We cant just close questions because some people find them pointless, or I would vote to close every COBOL question.

Comment: @user997112: "A lot"? Really? I'm guessing you haven't checked my profile to see how many I've asked. In any case, if you don't like "pointless", I suppose the correct phrase here would be "not a real question".

Comment: @Jerry, no the emphasis is your statement is an opinion. "Not a real question" is still an opinion.

Comment: @user997112: If you're really convinced that it shouldn't have been closed, the right place to discuss that would be on `meta`.

Comment: @Jerry, Then you should have done that 19 mins ago

Comment: @user997112 : The burden of asking a sensible question is on you, no one else. It takes multiple votes to close a question; if that many people agree that your question is poor, then maybe you should take the hint.

Comment: @ildjarn, what stupid logic. I presume tax is also a bad thing just because most people dislike it? 75% of SO hate micro-optimization questions- thats why it was closed. If you didn't like the question, don't bother reading it!

Comment: @Porcupine : The question would be closed because `static` has no bearing on performance; do you even know what it does? And how could I know whether or not I like the question until after I read it? Stupid logic indeed.

Comment: @ildjarn: So we close questions where there is an answer now? The question was: "Does the static keyword give any performance increase?" and you said "because static has no bearing on performance".... sounds like a normal Q/A on stackoverflow to me.... Are you going to close a question where somebody asks if the QPI bandwidth affects a single-threaded process just because the answer is "No" ??

Answer (score 7):

Considering that `static` and non-`static` variables have *extremely* different semantics, whether or not you can declare `static` really has nothing to do with performance.

Also, cache and other issues might well mean "no".

Answer (score 1):

it could be for data, if construction takes a long time (e.g. a precomputed buffer or something read from disk). often, this is only ideal when the data is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

@DeadMG already pointed out that changing a member variable to static would completely change the semantics, the same applies to a static function.

In general the answer is no, `static` doesn't help performance ([and neither does `const`](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm)) but one way that `static` can help is in an ELF shared library, where a static function isn't externally visible and so calls to it don't need to go through the [procedure linkage table](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/41), which gives a small performance benefit which can be worth considering when writing code for shared libraries.